# Node.JS server not sending data (or client not receiving)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a node.js server (using socket.io and express). I had everything functioning, but went to make my code into multiple files for organization.

Now, the client can send to the server (and the server can receive the data), but the server isn't sending the data back to the client (**or** the client isn't receiving the sent data).

Here's my server (app.js):

```
var variables = require('./variables');
var functions = require('./functions');
var connection = require('./connections');
var heartbeat = require('./heartbeat');

var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var config = JSON.parse(process.env.APP_CONFIG);
var mongoPassword = '1029384756';

variables.app.use('/client', variables.express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

mongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + config.mongo.user + ":" + mongoPassword + "@" + config.mongo.hostString, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    variables.db = db;

    // Routing
    variables.app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        response.sendFile(variables.path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.html'));
    });

    variables.server.listen(process.env.PORT);

    heartbeat.start();

    connection.startListening();
});
```

My variables.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
var db = null;
var onlinePlayers = {};


module.exports = {
    http,
    express,
    socketIO,
    path,
    app,
    server,
    io,
    db,
    onlinePlayers
}
```

My connections.js (where my io.on is)

```
const variables = require('./variables');

module.exports = {
    startListening: function () {
    variables.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('message', "Testing sending from server.");

        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            socket.emit('message', message);
        });

    --Snipped more variables.io.on (ignore {} mistakes, syntax is correct in code)
}
```

And my client (again, extremely snipped)

```
var socket = io();
var page = 0;

console.log("Loaded");

window.onload = function() {
    setPage(0);
}

socket.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

What will happen is, this:

Page will load. Client will print "Loaded", and then will print "Testing sending from server." (because of the socket.emit upon connection in connection.js)

If I go into the Client/Webpage's console and type:

```
socket.emit('message', "Hello");
```

My server will print out "Hello" (as it should), however my client doesn't then get the socket.emit from the server to print "Hello" back.

I'm completely stumped. Any help?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I do have a tip: Don't store your mongo password in code :) I hope you find a solution!

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations Yeah, that's just a temporary password haha. I ended up solving the issue (afaik), solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. At some point in my code (in this case it was inside of the setPage(0) function), the  tag for the index.js file that had the socket.ons was getting removed. Which means the server was sending the data, and the client was getting it, but just didn't have the script to tell it what to do with that data.